# sum of ideals in $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $I_1$ is a maximal ideal in $C^*$ algebra $A$,$I_2$ is an ideal of $A$,then $I_1+I_2$ is an ideal of $A$,can we conclude that $I_2\subset I_1$?

My thought:if there exists an element $x\in I_2$ which is not in $I_1$,then $I_1+I_2$ properly contains $I_1$,but $I_1$ is maximal,we get a contradiction.

Is my thought correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the additional hypothesis that $I_1+I_2$ is a *proper* ideal of $A$, then you can conclude that $I_2\subset I_1$.  For in this case we have $I_1=I_1+I_2\supset I_2$.  But it may happen that $I_1+I_2=A$, in which case you cannot conclude that $I_2\subset I_1$.

Note that this has nothing to do with $A$ being a $C^*$-algebra.  Your question could be stated for $A$ an arbitrary ring, and the same conclusion holds.